# Make button fadeOut and scroll to id

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, fadeout

I was wondering how to make a button disappear along with a heading, with the same button scrolling the page to the "about" section. Currently both the heading and the button will fade out on click, but the scroll doesn't work. Would I use an href? How do I call that in the js while also fading out?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the relevant code:

```
<h2 class="frame-4">Now!</h2>
<button href="javascript:jumpScroll()" class="btn">Join</button>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("h2").fadeOut()
        $("button").fadeOut()
      });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        function jumpScroll() {
            window.scroll(0,900);
        }
    </script>


<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want it to. The animated scrolling has been ripped off from the following: [CSS-Tricks: Smooth Scrolling](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

```
<nav class="btn-parent">
  <h2 class="frame-4">Now!</h2>
  <a href="#about" class="btn">Join</a>
</nav>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn").click(function(){
          $(".btn-parent").animate({opacity: 0});
        });

        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
  <h2>This is the about section</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
```

You can see a demo here: http://codepen.io/btpoe/pen/setbF

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 class="frame-4 fade">Now!</h2>
<button href="javascript:jumpScroll()" class="btn fade">Join</button>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function jumpScroll() {
            $('.fade').fadeOut();
            window.scrollTo(0,900);
        }
    </script>


<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Untested but if you add a class to the elements and then use jQuery within your function to fade the elements you should be good to go.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the answer. That made the button invisible immediately after showing and still no scroll capability. I'm thinking there is something wrong with how I'm trying to scroll. Is "window.scroll" a good way?

Comment: Sorry did not catch that. It should be scrollTo(xpos, ypos);

Comment: You could also use jQuery to scroll to an element id using $( "#id" ).scroll();

Answer (score 0):

You are already using jQuery, so you could just go with jQuery functions for triggering events. I'd also recommend using `animate` and `scrollTop` to make it more appealing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(".frame-4, button").fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $("body, html").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
            }, 200);
        });
    });
});
```

Working example: [Fade Title, Button & Scroll to Div](http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/Lk3gue6o/)

Answer (score 0):

Its more simple by using  location.hash

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $("h2").fadeOut()
    $("button").fadeOut()
    location.hash = '#about'
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/644mcwfu/)